# NumberFormatter parse returns false for Currency type on Symfony 2.5

Tags: php, internationalization, number-formatting, symfony-2.5

I have a Symfony 2.5 project where I'm trying to implement a currency validation on the back-end. For that reason there's the **NumberFormatter** class from PHP's Internationalization library with parsing all necessary inputs. For some reason though the `parse()` method always returns false.

A sample of the code:

```
private $numberFormatter;

function __construct()
{
    $this->numberFormatter =
        new \NumberFormatter("en-US", \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
}

//....

public function getDataAction(Request $request)
{
    $newValue = $this->numberFormatter->parse(
        $request->get('some_value')
    );
    //....
}
```

Nothing fancy really. 
Both *intl* and *mbstring* extensions are installed and running - checked with `phpinfo();`

I'm using PHP5.6, intl version is 1.1.0 with no default_locale (but I've tried setting it up to en-US and nothing changed). Also, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, with MySQL 5.7.12 and Apache2.

I've looked up here and on the net for a solution, but couldn't get any. Can you help, thanks?

Comment: What is the result of `$request->get('some_value')`?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 The int value, as coming from the form, for ex. 400

Comment: @ShiraNai7 Just tried forcing the parse() with  `$this->numberFormatter->parse( (string) $request->get('some_value') )` and `$this->numberFormatter->parse( (int) $request->get('some_value') )` but again - no luck.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` for `$style` makes the formatter expect a numeric amount, including the currency symbol:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en-US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($formatter->parse('123456')); // bool(false)
var_dump($formatter->parse('$123456')); // float(123456)
```

If you wish to parse generic numbers, use [one of the other styles](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants.unumberformatstyle), e.g. `\NumberFormatter::DECIMAL`:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en-US', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
var_dump($formatter->parse('1234565')); // float(1234565)
var_dump($formatter->parse('$123456')); // bool(false)
```

(`\NumberFormatter::DECIMAL` doesn't support currency symbols.)